# Offloading Magento admin panel

Tags: hosting, resources, magento, resource-management

I'm hoping that there's a way to host the Magento admin panel on a different box than I host the rest of my Magento install on. I'm not so worried about URLs - I can reverse proxy /admin in my web server config or use a subdomain.

The goal is to better manage resources for what is essentially two different sites - the admin panel and the store front end - and not have admin panel usage impact the web store.

Please let me know if your answer is theoretical or based on experience.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.  There is a setting in the admin panel you can adjust for your server.

Go to 
System > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Admin Base URL

change the "Use Custom Admin URL" settin to yes and then insert the URL for your separate admin server.

This is also a good thread too if you wish to do it on the router or index.php side of things.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/67820/